# Ubuntu. Create two files in the same directory and the second is a copy of first

Tags: file, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-12.04, copy-paste

Here is the problem I encountered today and took me hours to figure it out.
I wanted to create two text files in order to use them as arguments to my program. How did I create them? Firstly I pressed right click->Create new file and I named it `1text`. In order to create the second file I did not follow the same steps and I copied and pasted `1text` and renamed it as `2text`. Then I wrote some words in both files and ran the program:

```
./prog_name 1text 2text
```

Big surprise! I received the following message: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".
My question is: What happened when I created the files in that way (copy and paste for `2text`), because when I created `2text` as the first file (right click->Create new file), the program ran successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: What happened when I created the files in that way (copy and paste for 2text), because when I created 2text as the first file (right click->Create new file), the program ran successfully?

Your program has a bug, which is (possibly) exposed by the particular contents of the two input files.

*How* you created these files is irrelevant. It is likely that the files created  in different way were subtly different, perhaps missing a trailing newline, or having one extra one.

To find the bug, run your program under valgrind:

```
valgrind ./prog_name 1text 2text
```

It is very likely that valgrind will tell you about your bug right away.